# T-SQL WHERE clause - comparing column to itself fails on null columns

Tags: t-sql, null, where-clause

I usually use a construct like this to apply filters to columns:

```
CREATE TABLE test(a int NOT NULL, b int NULL)
--insert some data
INSERT INTO test(a,b) values (1,1)
INSERT INTO test(a,b) values (1,NULL)

declare @a int
declare @b int
set @a = 1
--@b is null at this time

select * from test
  where a = @a
    and b = isnull(@b,b)
```

This only selects the first row.

For example, if this was a stored procedure and argument `@b` was null, I could specify its value to 'enable' it in the `where` clause, and specify `NULL` value to select where b=b, which would be true for each column, **BUT** if there is a `NULL` value in `b` column, it does not get selected. Is there a standard way to deal with this? So what should I use in the above example query to select all rows even if `b` column has null values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking NULL values you need to do it as `b is null`

You can change query as -

```
select * from test
  where a = @a
    and b = isnull(@b,b)
    or (@b is null and b is null)
```

Comment: thanks, but that works if @b is NULL, but if @a = 1, @b = 1 the query should only return the first row (with your fix it returns both of them)

Comment: OK, changing it to     select * from test
      where a = @a
        and (b = isnull(@b,b)
   or (b is null and @b is null)) did the trick! thanks again

Comment: @Axarydax - Aaaah.. Just in time. You got the answer before my edit.